# How to disable some commands on root user?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, root

Some commands like `npm`, `composer`, `git`, etc are not recommended run as root user. But sometimes I forget to run it when I log in as root, and my coworkers also sometimes do that too. That makes some files/dirs  unable to be accessed by non-root users, which sometimes makes our website/apps errors. Is there any way to disable those commands when run as a root user? at least give warning/confirmation before running those commands.

Comment: Fix whatever problem with your systems or workflow that requires you and your co-workers to use (abuse) root so frequently.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for your advice, but actually I am a very rare abused root user. And  I can change my workflow, but I don't have a power to change my co-worker workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aliases to prevent those commands from execution.
for example for preventing command `git` from execution you can append this line to the file `/root/.bashrc`:

```
alias git='echo You are root!'
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm looking for

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur just a note that this won't apply if you do `sudo git`.

Comment: @muru yeah, I also tried it, and no problem, I and my co-workers never use `sudo` on commands that I mentioned. I just want to prevent the commands from `sudo su` or root user login.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu does not have a root user so I am assuming that you are using `sudo su`.

There are very few situations where this is needed. It's better that you learn to use `sudo` effectively only when superuser access is actually needed.

When you are using `sudo su`, everything you run is as if you were using the root user. By definition, the root user can do anything they want. You cannot restrict what can be done by sudoers when using `sudo`.

You cannot restrict the root user, nor can you restrict what someone with sudo privileges can do when using `sudo`, so what you are asking is impossible.

The better option is to correct your workflow so that you are not overusing `sudo` when it is not necessary.